# Why do almost all systems have positive heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

From a fundamental stat mech perspective, the heat capacity $C$ of a system is given by
$$C = -\frac{\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial E} \right)^2}{\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial E^2}},$$
where $S$ is the entropy and $E$ is the internal energy. So the heat capacity has the opposite sign as $\partial^2S/\partial E^2$, and is positive iff $S(E)$ is concave down.

It isn't obvious to me why $S(E)$ should be concave down in general. And yet, empirically, pretty much every single system you ever come across seems to have positive heat capacity, except for black holes (according to our best current understanding of semiclassical quantum gravity).

Is there some fundamental reason why $S(E)$ is concave down for pretty much everything except for black holes? If so, what makes black holes *fundamentally* different? (I'm not just looking for the Bekenstein-Hawking formula $S \propto M^2$.)

It isn't enough to say that systems must have positive heat capacity because their temperatures equalize when they are placed into thermal contact. This claim gets the direction of causation backwards: temperatures equalize because the systems have positive heat capacity, not vice versa. (There might be some more sophisticated stability argument though that shows that systems with negative capacity can exist but must be unstable. But even if that's true, which seems plausible but not obvious, then it still isn't clear to me why a typical lifetime would be so short that we'd never observe these systems in everyday life.)

Comment: Lynden-Bell’s “[Negative specific heat in astronomy, physics and chemistry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9812172)” is an interesting read in this vein.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the answer just was that negative heat capacity was unstable, and the argument is not sophisticated at all. If you have a positive and negative heat capacity object in thermal context, heat transfer will _increase_ the temperature difference.

Comment: @knzhou That isn't quite true. Your statement is true if both bodies have negative heat capacity. If one has positive heat capacity and the other has negative, then heat transfer will increase/decrease both bodies' temperatures, but not necessarily increase the temperature difference. (E.g when a black hole evaporates, the interior and exterior both heat up.) But the instability argument doesn't seem to be enough to me anyway, because the second law of thermodynamics says that *any* non-maximal-entropy system is unstable - and yet the entire field is the study of such unstable systems.

Comment: if two bodies have negative capacities then between them could entropy transfer spontaneously from a higher to a lower temperature?

Comment: @hyportnex I don't know what you mean by "entropy transfer", as entropy is a global property and is not conserved so you can't really "transfer" it. Do you mean "energy transfer", and do you mean "lower to higher temperature", since energy transfer from higher to lower temperature is the usual direction?

Comment: I try to avoid the word "heat" $\delta q = (T_h-T_{\ell})dS$ as it is ambiguous but there is no ambiguity in entropy and the temperatures. I asked my question because I do not have any intuition as to how matter could behave if it had negative heat capacity. So, if you like, between two negative heat capacity bodies would "heat" spontaneously flow from a higher to lower temperature, or is the other way? And, even more importantly can this be experimentally verified?

Comment: @hyportnex Re "Between two negative heat capacity bodies would heat spontaneously flow from a higher to lower temperature?": No. Heat always flows from higher to lower temperature (or more precisely, from lower to higher $\beta$), regardless of the sign of either body's temperature or heat capacity. The sign of the heat capacity only determines whether the body *responds* to that heat flow by getting hotter or colder.

Comment: Thank you. That was my 1st question, but can it be verified experimentally?

Comment: @hyportnex Not sure, because systems with negative heat capacity are very rare (which is the whole point of my question). I vaguely remember reading that stars can have negative heat capacity, but I assume that they're too far away and change temperature over too long time scales for us to verify that directly.